# How to create key-value pairs from textFile

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I want to use a member in a RDD element as a key, how can i do this 
this is my data:

```
2 1
4 1
1 2
6 3
7 3
7 6
6 7
3 7
```

I want to create key/value pairs such that key is a element, also value is next element;

I wrote this code:

```
def main(args: Array[String])
 {
   System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","C:\\spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6\\winutil")
   val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[4]")
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

   val lines = sc.textFile("followers.txt")
    .flatMap{x => (x.indexOfSlice(x1),x.indexOfSlice(x2))} 

}
```

but it is not true and it wont determine the index of elements;
every two number is a line

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but if you are simply looking to split your data into key-value pairs, you just need to do this:

```
val lines = sc.textFile("followers.txt").map(s => {
  val substrings = s.split(" ")
  (substrings(0), substrings(1))
})
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: thank you very much, but when i want to use lines as an RDD for groupByKey operation i'll get error

Comment: i found out, thanks, i worte this: val aggrigateNeighbors = lines.groupByKey().collect().foreach(println), sorry, i'm a beginner but im doing a project in spark